# Index error when deleting and creating an object in SQLite's table

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-7.0

C# and .net MAUI beginner here.

I am struggling with resolving the problem of Index being out of range when I delete the object in the SQLite database and create any new objects in replacement.

My app contains 2 Pages and 2 additional classes with the code behind.

The problem seems to be in the db_refresh on MainPage method where eachTerm count is not decreased compared to the termlist count causing Index to error out. Here is the error syntax:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'
```

However, the proper number of buttons is being generated in the generateInterface method.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public static List<Term> termList = new List<Term>();
    public static string dbLocation = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "MyData.db");
    public MainPage()
    {
        File.Delete(dbLocation);
        dbActions.initiateDbTables();
        InitializeComponent();
        db_refresh();
        generateInterface();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        AppShell.SetBackgroundColor(this, Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0));
        db_refresh();
        generateInterface();
    }
    public static void db_refresh()
    {
        termList.Clear();
        var dataBase = new SQLiteConnection(dbLocation);
        var queriedTerm = dataBase.Query<Term>("SELECT * FROM Terms");
        foreach (Term eachTerm in queriedTerm)
        {
           termList.Add(eachTerm);
        }
    }
    public void generateInterface()
    {

        termView.Children.Clear();

        foreach (Term myTerm in termList)
        {
            Button termNameButton = new Button
            {
                Text = myTerm.termName,
                BackgroundColor = Colors.Green,
                TextColor = Colors.White,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            };
            termNameButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new TermPage(myTerm.termId));
            };
            termView.Children.Add(termNameButton);
        }

        Button termAddButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Add Term",
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Black,
            TextColor = Colors.White,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
        };
        termAddButton.Clicked += void (sender, args) => clickNewTerm();
        termView.Children.Add(termAddButton);
    }
    public void clickNewTerm()
    {
        dbActions.addNewDbTerm();
        generateInterface();
    }
}
```

The delete Term method is located in the separated page (TermPage) accessed when I click on the Terms button in the MainScreen. Here is the code of the TermPage:

```
public Term currentTerm;
public SQLiteConnection dbConnect = new SQLiteConnection(MainPage.dbLocation);
public TermPage(int termId)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ButtonAdd();
    Term myTerm = MainPage.termList[termId - 1];
    currentTerm = myTerm;
    termName.Text = currentTerm.termName;
}
private void ButtonAdd()
{
    Button deleteTermButton = new Button()
    {
        Text = "Delete Term",
        BackgroundColor = Colors.Red,
        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
    };
    deleteTermButton.Clicked += void (sender, args) => actionDeleteTerm();
    TermPageView.Children.Add(deleteTermButton);
}
public async void actionDeleteTerm()
{
    dbConnect.Delete(currentTerm);
    MainPage.db_refresh();
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Here is the class that adds a new Term:

```
public class dbActions
{
    public static void initiateDbTables()
    {
        var dbLocation = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "MyData.db");
        var dbConnect = new SQLiteConnection(dbLocation);
        dbConnect.CreateTable<Term>();
    }
    public static void addNewDbTerm()
    {
        var dbConnect = new SQLiteConnection(MainPage.dbLocation);
        var dbQuery = dbConnect.Query<Term>($"SELECT * FROM Terms ORDER BY termId DESC LIMIT 1");
        if (dbQuery.Count != 0)
        {
            Term topTerm = dbQuery.First();
            string termName = "Term " + (topTerm.termId + 1).ToString();
            Term newTerm = new Term(termName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(60));
            dbConnect.Insert(newTerm);
            MainPage.db_refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            Term newTerm = new Term("Term1", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(60));
            dbConnect.Insert(newTerm);
            MainPage.db_refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use termList.Clear() to refresh the Index, but I am not sure if that's the correct approach.

Comment: Which specific line throws the exception?

Comment: `Term myTerm = MainPage.termList[termId - 1]; `

right at the moment when I try to access any new object in Term list after deleting an object that was prior creating a new one

Comment: What is the value of termId at that point?  And the value of termList.Count?

Comment: The error message says *"Index was out of range"*. Jason is asking you what the index was and what the range was. That's information that you need to get for yourself as part of your own debugging, which you need to do before posting a question. If you don't know how to debug - it's not part of most general language tutorials and many paid courses shamelessly ignore it too - then you should stop what you're doing and learn that first. It's a critical skill for all developers and learning ASAP will save you a lot of time. It will also save us asking for information that you should already have.

Comment: What you are doing is **NOT** the way to use a database. Instead of loading everything and passing an array index to the second page to look up the item in a static array, pass the `termID` to the page and run an SQL statement with a WHERE clause that will retrieve just that item.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I want to load everything and have every term that is in the database as clickable buttons where once I click on a term button to navigate to the TermsPage, it displays further details of that Term. My understanding was that I am already passing the termID that I pulled from the database to the TermPage. So, instead of decreasing the termId from the database to find the same termId in the Table list and pull the data from that list, should I run the query and get the details of that term based on the termId passed from the MainScreen? Could you help with the code, please?

Comment: @Jason - the termId value at that point (where, at a starting point I had 2 terms hardcoded, then added one more, then deleted the third one and re-added the third one) was 4, where the termList.Count was 3.

Comment: if there are 3 items in the list, there indexes are [0,1,2].  I think you may be confused about the difference between the **Primary Key** of an object and its index within a list.  They are NOT the same thing

Comment: @Jason, well it seems that you are right. So it would be nice if you or anyone else would help explaining it to me on this example so I could understand how can I fix it, or show me the fix so I can understand it. If termId that I parse to the TermPage is the Primary Key of the object in the database, then when I delete that term and recreate it, shouldn't it receive the same termId as the one previously deleted? It seems that it is getting a next one in order.

Comment: garlando90: I'm very confused. Please point out what part of @jmcilhinney's comment was arrogant and what didn't bring value? His point is an important one, one that if you follow, can only help you *greatly* with your coding development and abilities.

Comment: Well, firstly, "Index was out of range" - I can read English. It seems that I have to guess what information @jmcilhinney needed to help me. Secondly, mentioning to learn debugging without providing some insights or links or some content on how to do that is soooo helpful. Lastly, for me, the tone of that message is aggressive and intimidating. Maybe you see it differently because you consider yourself a developer. I do not consider myself as one, and probably this person's comment would be totally different if I didn't mention I am a beginner.

Comment: Yes, we see it very differently, and I think that it is easy to infer tone that simply doesn't exist when reading anonymous communication online. In my experience, it is always best to assume good intentions unless it is blatantly proven otherwise.

Comment: *"It seems that I have to guess what information @jmcilhinney needed to help me"*. No, you didn't have to guess. It literally tells you in the error message. If an index is out of range, the index and the range are the issue so that is the information that you should be looking for first. *"mentioning to learn debugging without providing some insights or links or some content on how to do that is soooo helpful"*. I assume that anyone capable of writing code and posting a question here is capable of using a search engine and searching for "how to debug vb.net" or the like.

Comment: *"the tone of that message is aggressive and intimidating"*. In my experience, telling someone that they should have done something that they didn't is often interpreted as aggressive when it's simply not. It's instructive but many people don't want anything remotely resembling criticism. You know you're a beginner so I would hope that you know that you're doing things wrong, so why get bent out of shape when they are pointed out to you? The point is to push you to think like a developer - to ask yourself what is needed when something goes wrong rather than wait for others to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to retrieve an item by id from a list of objects, do this

```
Term myTerm = MainPage.termList.First(t => t.termId == termId);
```

Comment: see my edit - use `First` instead of `Where` to select a single object

Comment: Wooohoo! this fix works as well now with `First` instead of `Where`. Thank you so much @Jason for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I had to post the question in order to find the answer myself lol. I finally fixed the issue modifying the termId prior parsing it to the TermPage with this line:

`int termId = termList.IndexOf(myTerm) + 1;`

and then instead of parsing myterm.termId I parsed the termId variable.

`await Navigation.PushAsync(new TermPage(termId));`